# MySQL temp table cursor

Tags: mysql

I am writing MySQL stored procedure and I am having problems iterating trough temporary table rows with the cursor. I assume that the data is being selected before the table is populated, but not sure. Here are basic steps in my procedure:

```
- DECLARE articles_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT title FROM FoundIn;
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FoundIn ( ... );
- Populate the table ...
- Open the cursor and try to fetch data
```

And every time i get NOT FOUND in my cursor. If the problem is that cursor is declared before the table, is there a way to work around it? Also, I need distinct values to iterate trough, so I suppose a WHILE loop is not an option.

Comment: Do you really need a cursor? What are you doing in the loop?

Comment: You cannot declare a cursor before you define the table it runs on.  That is both a logical and programming error.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me what is the correct way of iterating over a temporary table once it is populated? I need to extract just distinct rows and access each one.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work you will need to use prepared statements:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someProc()
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FoundIn ( ... );
  SET @selectSql=CONCAT("SELECT * FROM FoundIn");
  PREPARE stmt FROM @selectSql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Or alternative: Use 2 procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someProc()
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FoundIn ( ... );
  CALL someProc2();
END;
```

In which someProc2 contains the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks Norbert, prepared statement fetched the results. Now is there a way to iterate trough them? The thing is, I need to get each value for one column form temp table and do something with it (ether pass it to other stored procedure or do it in loop).